# Keep CDATA for xstl transformation?

Tags: java, xml, saxon

I'm doing a xstl transformation with saxon from an XML document.
The doc is not standard-valid XML, and I want to preserve all `<![CDATA[<` elements that are found in there.

However using the .xsl file for transformation with

```
Transformer trans = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File("foo.xsl"));
trans.transform(new StreamSource(new File("foo.xml"), new StreamResult(new File("output.xml")));
```

results in stripping out these CDATA entries. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, as the distinction whether a text originated from a cdata section is not available in the datamodel used by xslt. You can however define in your stylesheet that certain result elements are to be wrapped inside cdata. This is done using the [`cdata-section-elements` attribute of the `xsl:output` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output) in your stylesheet.

Comment: This works perfectly! Just another question: how can I exclude specific elements? Lets say I have a `<my:request>` and `<my:request name="test">`, how can I exclude the request with attribut name?

Comment: @membersound: You mean, `my:request` should be wrapped in cdata, except when it has a name attribute with a value of "test"? I don't think thats possible as `cdata-section-elements` only lists the qnames of elements.

Comment: yes everything inside `<my:request/>` should be wrapped. Everything where name="test" should NOT be wrapped with cdata.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Andrew Welch's LexEv tool (bundled I believe with KernowForSaxon), which preprocesses CDATA start and end tags into something different (processing instructions perhaps?) that's visible in the XSLT data model and thus available to the application.