# Serializing Java DOM Document to XML: Add CData Elements

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax

I am constructing an XML DOM Document with a SAX parser. I have written methods to handle the `startCDATA` and `endCDATA` methods and in the `endCDATA` method I construct a new CDATA section like this:

```
public void onEndCData() {
    xmlStructure.cData = false;
    Document document = xmlStructure.xmlResult.document;
    Element element = (Element) xmlStructure.xmlResult.stack.peek();
    CDATASection section = document.createCDATASection(xmlStructure.stack.peek().characters);
    element.appendChild(section);
}
```

When I serialize this to an XML file I use the following line to configure the transformer:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS, "con:setting");
```

Never the less no `<![CDATA[` tags appear in my XML file and instead all backets are escaped to `&gt;` and `&lt;`, this is no problem for other tools but it is a problem for humans who need to read the file as well. I am positive that the "con:setting" tag is the right one. So is there maybe a problem with the namespace prefix?

<s>Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727161/keep-cdata-for-xstl-tranformation) indicates that it is not possible to omit the CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS property and generally serialize all CDATA nodes without escaping the data. Is that information correct, or are there maybe other methods that the author of the answer was not aware of?</s>

**Update:** It seems I had a mistake in my code. When using the `document.createCDATASection()` function, and then serializing the code with the Transformer it **DOES** output CDATA tags, even without the use of the `CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS` property in the transformer.

Comment: You can't preserve CDATA from the input with a Transformer that runs an XSLT stylesheet, maybe the rules are different for a no-op transformer (or more likely the results will be processor-specific).

Comment: It seems they are as I get CDATA tags in my saved XML file now.

Comment: It would be interesting to see if you get the same behaviour with different `TransformerFactory` implementations - if you switch to Saxon, for example, does the no-op Transformer still preserve CDATA?  I can't see anything in the JAXP specifications that defines it either way, but I know that the DOM LS mechanism will definitely work as you require in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a namespace-aware DOM. The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/OutputKeys.html#CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS) say you need to provide the [Qualified Name Representation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/package-summary.html#qname-delimiter) of the element:

```
private static String qualifiedNameRepresentation(Element e) {
  String ns = e.getNamespaceURI();
  String local = e.getLocalName();
  return (ns == null) ? local : '{' + ns + '}' + local;
}
```

So the value of the property will be of the form `{http://your.conn.namespace}setting`.

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS, "con:setting");
```

try replacing `"con:setting"` with `"{http://con.namespace/}setting"`

using the appropriate namespace

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a no-op `Transformer` to serialize your DOM tree you could try using the DOM-native ["load and save" mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/package-summary.html), which should preserve the `CDATASection` nodes from the DOM tree and write them as CDATA sections in the resulting XML.

```
DOMImplementationLS ls = (DOMImplementationLS)document.getImplementation();
LSOutput output = ls.createLSOutput();
LSSerializer ser = ls.createLSSerializer();
try (FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(...)) {
  output.setByteStream(outStream);
  output.setEncoding("UTF-8");
  ser.write(document, output);
}
```